# logic behind SQL code not clear

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have come across an SQL code as below

```
SELECT  DISTINCT FLD1, FLD2, FLD3, FLD4 FROM            
TBL1 WHERE FLD1 = 'MFG' AND FLD2 = '1'
```

My doubt is on the DISTINCT keyword here applied before FLD1. There is a filtration condition to select only those records where FLD1 = 'MFG'. So does the distinct make any difference there?

I have run the same SQL without the DISTINCT and the number of records retrieved is the same with the DISTINCT.

This is written for DB2 database on iSeries.

Comment: `distinct` applies to **all** columns in the select list, not just the first one

Comment: This is the answer I was expecting. So if there are multiple records with same value for fields FLD1, FLD2, FLD3, FLD4, only one record is selected. So is this equivalent to SELECT  FLD1, FLD2, FLD3, FLD4 FROM            
TBL1 WHERE FLD1 = 'MFG' AND FLD2 = '1' GROUP BY FLD1, FLD2, FLD3, FLD4

Answer (score 3):

it eliminates all the duplicate records and fetch only unique records.

example:

Table Employee

```
Id     Name      Salary
1      Alex      2000
2      Alxender  1000
3      Paul      2000
4      Alex      2000
```

```
select distinct Salary 
from Employees;
```

it will return:

```
Salary
2000
1000
```

```
select distinct Name,Salary 
from Employees;
```

will return:

```
Name      Salary
Alex      2000
Alxender  1000
Paul      2000
```

The query:

```
select distinct Salary,Name 
from Employees 
where salary = 2000;
```

will return:

```
Name      Salary
Alex      2000    
Paul      2000
```

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. Are you saying that only one record per unique combination of FLD1, FLD2, FLD3, FLD4 will be pulled?

Comment: it will remove duplicate values from each column

Comment: Yes DISTINCT will remove duplicate rows from the results set so one record per unique combination of FLD1, FLD2, FLD3, FLD4.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Please see my question again. the SQL i have is something like "select distinct Salary,ID,Name from Employees where salary = 2000;" What would this return?

Comment: check edit again.  i hope now it will be clear to you.

Comment: @user3311539, including ID in the select makes `DISTINCT` pointless, as ID should be a unique key.  Thus, with or without distinct, all the rows would be unique.